# Why Cannot I use java script method Sort() on Array objects created from jquery $.makeArray()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why Cannot I use java script method Sort() on Array objects created from jquery api $.makeArray()
For Eg:
My DOM has these elements

```
<ul id="languages">
 <li>First</li>
 <li>Second</li>
 <li>Third</li>
 <li>Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

I tried to sort and append them.

`var elems = document.getElementsByTagName( "li" );
var arr = $.makeArray( elems );
arr.sort();
$( arr ).appendTo( "#languages" );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This should be the solution to your problem - hope this helps

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName( "li" );
var arr = $.makeArray( elems ); 
arr.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML;
});
$( arr ).appendTo( "#languages" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a custom sort method to sort the elements based on the contents

```js
//You can use .get() to get an array of elements from a jQuery object
var arr = $("li").get();
arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
  return $(o1).text().localeCompare($(o2).text())
});
$(arr).appendTo("#languages");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="languages">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `toArray()` to convert a jquery object wrapped around dom objects..

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName( "li" );
var sorted = $(elems).toArray().sort();
```